# Using CSS Selectors to grab element which meets mutilple :not "conditions"

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

I am looking to grab any element from the DOM that meets 2 basic conditions using the `:not` pseudo-class.

Here is my line of code:

`document.querySelectorAll('textarea:not([id*=xyz]):not([style*=hidden])')`

So I want to get any text area that:

1. as an id that does not contain 'xyx' and
2. does not have 'hidden' in the inline styles.

It seems that this grabs on an "or" basis as opposed to an "and" basis.

For example, it wont grab an element with an id of 'xyz' which does not have 'hidden' in the inline styles since it met the earlier criteria.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem — http://jsbin.com/texero/1/edit?html,js,output — only the field which matches all the conditions matches.

Comment: By definition, all components of a selector are AND-ed. So your problem lies elsewhere. However, building any dependency on a specific string in the style attribute is horrible coding practice. You should take one or two steps back.

Comment: I understand this is bad practice, but this is what i'm working with

Comment: @Ricardo Ruiz: The quotes aren't required there.

Comment: @RicardoRuiz — Quote marks are not needed since `xyz` and `hidden` are valid identifiers.

Comment: Yeah I noticed a bit late, this is working for me as it is though.

Comment: I think the problem is due to the mismatch between two statements in the question. I read the latter while the others seem to have taken the former. The bullet point says *select only element whose id doesn't contain xyz **and**  doesn't have hidden in inline styles* whereas the last statement indicates the opposite. OP's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947143/using-css-selectors-to-grab-element-which-meets-mutilple-not-conditions/37947295#comment63343683_37947295) seems to indicate they do want to select element whose id IS xyz but has no hidden in inline styles.

Comment: The correct phrasing would've probably been ***ignore*** all elements whose `id*='xyz'` ***and*** `style*='hidden'`.

Comment: Your definitions of "or" and "and" are at odds with the definitions as used in Boolean logic. Please clarify.

Comment: @BoltClock How did you manage to close this with only three votes?

Comment: To avoid this type of confusion, you're better off avoiding `:not()` altogether, and instead writing 2-3 rules which capture what you want to do, one for the default case, one for either condition not matching, using the old-fashioned comma.

Comment: @torazaburo: Moderator close votes are binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example: i would like to be able to grab this element: `<textarea id="123-xyz"></textarea>` but not `<textarea id="123-xyz" style="visibility:hidden"></textarea>` specifically using one line of JS

Based on [**your comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37947143/using-css-selectors-to-grab-element-which-meets-mutilple-not-conditions/37947295#comment63343683_37947295) (quoted above), it seems like the actual question is to ***ignore*** any text area whose `id` contains `xyz` and also has a `style` which contains `hidden`. Or, in other words the need is to ***select all text-areas that don't contain a combination of*** `id*='xyz'` ***and*** `style*='hidden'`.

Note that ***not(x and y)*** is not the same as ***not(x) and not(y)***. The former is the one you are looking for but the latter is what the code in question does.

```
           |--------|---------------------------|----------------------------|
           |   y -> |           true            |           false            |
           | x      |                           |                            |
           |--------|---------------------------|----------------------------|
           | true   | not(x and y) = false      | not(x and y) = true        |
           |        | not(x) and not(y) = false | not(x) and not(y) = false  |
           |--------|---------------------------|----------------------------|
           | false  | not(x and y) = true       | not(x and y) = true        |
           |        | not(x) and not(y) = false | not(x) and not(y) = true   |
           |--------|---------------------------|----------------------------|
```

So, you should use a group of selectors to achieve this instead of chaining the `:not`. When chaining of `not` is done, the selector in question means select only elements whose `id` doesn't contain `xyz` and `style` doesn't contain `hidden`. This would mean that the first element in your comment will also not be selected as its `id` contains `xyz`, so one part of the AND is falsy meaning the whole condition is falsy.

When a group of two selectors (like in the below snippet) is used:

- First element matches both selectors and so gets the outline.
- Second element matches the second selector (but not the first) and so gets the outline.
- Third element doesn't match either selector and so doesn't get the outline.
- Fourth element matches the first selector (but not the second) and so gets the outline.
- Fifth element matches the second selector (but not the first) and so gets the outline.

```css
textarea:not([id*=xyz]), textarea:not([style*=hidden]) {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<textarea rows='5' cols='5'></textarea>
<textarea rows='5' cols='5' id='123-xyz'></textarea>
<textarea rows='5' cols='5' id='123-xyz' style='property: hidden'></textarea>
<textarea rows='5' cols='5' id='abc' style='property: hidden'></textarea>
<textarea rows='5' cols='5' id='xyz' style='property: hiden'></textarea>
```

Comment: Example: i would like to be able to grab this element: `<textarea id="123-xyz"></textarea>` but not `<textarea id="123-xyz" style="visibility:hidden"></textarea>` specifically using one line of JS

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear — If you only care about the visibility why are you testing for the ID at all?

Comment: @Quentin youre right, i complicated this in my head way too much. derp. thanks

Comment: Guys, before continuing to pile on downvotes, please read the clarification given by OP in comments and validate the answer based on that. This is really really cheap behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve that should be to use this selector: `textarea:not([id*="xyz"][style*="hidden"])` (target textarea that does not have an id with "xyz" and a style attribute with "hidden"). Unfortunately, it does not seem to be correctly implemented yet... (may be a typo issue, see snippet below)

```css
textarea[id*="xyz"][style*="hidden"] { background-color: yellow }
textarea:not([id*="xyz"][style*="hidden"]) { background-color: red }
```

```html
<textarea id="__xyz__" style="__hidden__">I am yellow!</textarea><br />
<textarea id="__xyz__" style="something else">I should be red!</textarea><br />
<textarea id="something else" style="__hidden__">I should be red!</textarea><br />
<textarea id="something else" style="something else">I should be red!</textarea><br />
```

So, I suggest to do that in another way:

```js
var NodeList2Array = function( nodes )
{
  var arr = [], i = nodes.length;
  
  while( i-- )
  {
    arr[i] = nodes[i];
  }
  
  return arr;
}; // yes, NodeList are not Array :(

// grab all textarea
var all = NodeList2Array( document.querySelectorAll('textarea') );
// grab all textarea that match unexpected case
var exclude = NodeList2Array( document.querySelectorAll('textarea[id*=xyz][style*=hidden]') );
// then filter `exclude` out of `all`
var expected = all.filter( function( item ){
  // not found in `exclude` array, I want it!
  return exclude.indexOf( item ) === -1; 
} );

var i = expected.length;
while( i-- )
{
  expected[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="__xyz__" style="__hidden__">I should not be red!</textarea><br />
<textarea id="__xyz__" style="something else">I should be red!</textarea><br />
<textarea id="something else" style="__hidden__">I should be red!</textarea><br />
<textarea id="something else" style="something else">I should be red!</textarea><br />
```

### Mr_Green's Answer

Since, the post was closed but I felt it is an interesting question. So, I am providing my answer here which is shorter version of the above code:

```
var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
var filteredTextAreas = Array.prototype.filter.call(textareas, function(el){
  return !(/xyz/.test(el.id) && /hidden/.test(el.getAttribute('style')));
});

// Now do anything with filteredTextAreas
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as6a6myq/)**

Comment: What is not correctly implemented, or what may be a typo?

Comment: Yes nodelist is not array. You can do like this: `Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(el){ /* array converted element here */ })`